# correct coding structure in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm still using the life cycle methods, so my question is since `componentDidMount()` acts like a constructor I'm planning to initialize everything there:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="done-container" style={this.style().taskContainer}>
                <span style={this.style().title}>Done</span>
                {
                    this.props.done.map((d) => (

                    <div className={`done ${this.state.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`} id={this.props.done.id}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        this.props.setTaskID(d.id);
                        this.setToActive(e); //3.Call <-----
                        this.props.arrowStyleToDone();
                    }}>

                    </div>

                    ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    setToActive  //1.Declare <----
    componentDidMount() {
        //2.Initialize  <-----
        this.setToActive = (e) => {
            if(!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
                e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
                e.currentTarget.classList.add('border-done')
                this.props.closeAllTasks();
                this.props.closeAllDoing();
            } else {
                e.currentTarget.classList.remove('active');
                e.currentTarget.classList.remove('border-done')
                this.props.disableArrowButton();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is that if I declare everything inside the class which looks very ugly in my opinion, but then initializing everything on `componentDidMount()` instead of putting everything inside the `render()`, my web app will be faster because it won't need to declare and initialize everything every render.

Is this correct? and should I put the declaring and initialization on top of `render()`? but the `componenDidMount()` is called after the initial render.

Comment: I think that a code structure question may be too opinion based for this site.  This site is for code that is not working and needs to be fixed.  You question is certainly valid, but I think it might be a better fit for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange as it's goal is to review code and provide insight on how you can make you code better.  The goal **here** is to make broken code work.

Comment: The constructor acts like a constructor. Component did mount acts like a listener called when the component is rendered

Comment: @quirimmo so should I initialilze in the constructor? or should I just directly create arrow functions and properties inside the class but outside the render() and componentDidMount()? what's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

> and should I put the declaring and initialization on top of render()

Typically the `render` function is put at the end of your class

> but then initializing everything on componentDidMount() my web app will be faster because it won't need to declare and initialize everything every render.

I don't think you understand how React/classes work... If you do

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  someFunc() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

the `someFunc` function isn't re-declared every render. If you are worried about `this` binding issues, you can just do

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.someFunc = this.someFunc.bind(this);
  }

  someFunc() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```